# Reindexing in Magento with AOE Scheduler

Tags: cron, reindex

I installed the rather nifty looking AOE Scheduler extension.  It's all working good and I can see a task called;

```
catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all
```

but from what I can gather this only reindexes the Index Product Prices.

My question is this:  **How can I add a task to AOE that reindexes the ENTIRE Index?**  I can see in my index at the moment that Product Attributes needs reindexing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add tasks via the scheduler. It only represents tasks set in the `<crontab>` tag in other modules `config.xml` files.

To reindex use the servers `crontab` and add a task like

```
15 9 * * * php /path/to/website/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

This task will run the Indexer on all indexes every day at a quarter pas nine

Comment: Sander:  Thank you for that.  Is running it once a day suitable for a busy store.  We add products and make category changes & attributes every day, so how often is best to run it, do you think?

Comment: Hm if you want to run it once, set the indexes to manual in the backend in case you didn't do that already and then just run it at 17:00. Should be a bit more quiet around that time due to people leaving for home and it will process the data you have changed that day